# How the NS records in zone file work?

Tags: dns

How the NS records in the zone file for current zone work? I guess it works like below,am i right?

For example we have a recursive name serverA for example.com zone and a name serverB for sub.example.com zone which is sub domain of example.com.and a host host1.sub.example.com lies in sub.example.com.

1、I execute dig @ServerA host1.sub.example.com on a client
2、ServerA checks its zone file(or its cache),find NS records and A records of sub.example.com
3、ServerA "first time" queries ServerB because NS records in its own zone file point to ServerB
4、ServerB returns the NS records in its zone file to ServerA telling ServerA "hey,these are my domain's NS records,they are promised to be correct.they are official,they are the correct one,if they are different from what you have,put yours in trash"
5、ServerA picks one name server from last step(maybe the picked one is ServerB),if ServerB is picked up,ServerA need "second time" queries ServerB  ,and asks "what's the A record of host1.sub.example.com ".

even though ServerA will pick ServerB,it still need to do the second query,am i right?

Answer (score 0):

DNS is not concerned about the full DNS, only to whatever is queried.

If you make a dns request for sub.example.com, you will get the NS record for sub.example.com, and the server then handles that request.

There is no need to query example.com itself, unless somewhere in the whole reasoning of getting to sub.example.com, there is also something that requests information from example.com itself.

For example, if you have a webscript on sub.example.com that checks if https://example.com/test.php exists, then it will make contact with example.com but otherwise not.

The primary function of DNS is to translate a name to an address. So you put in a domain name, and you get out an IP address and possibly some information about the domain, such as a text record.

Because of this, the less information DNS has to check, the faster it is. This is both its strength and weakness.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I didn't point out what confuse me: I have no idea how name server handles inconsistence between NS records between parent zone and sub zone.

Comment: As I tried to convey, they are completely ignored, because the client only queries either the subdomain or the main domain. There usually is no reason to query both, but even if both are queried, they are queried as different queries.